# Unnecessary join in Entity framework when using imported function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I have an **Employee** table in my database and a SQL table value function that return exactly same structure as my employee table. I'm changing some fields value (Like GroupNumber) of table in my function. I imported the function in EF and set return type To Employee entity. 
Now I run the following query:

```
IQueryable<Employee> employeeSearchResult = this.Context.EmployeeStateAtDate(persianDate.ToDateTime());
var result = employeeSearchResult.Where(q => q.Group.Title.contains("XYZ")).Select(q => q.EmployeeN umber).ToList()
```

The query generated is as the following

```
SELECT  [Filter1].[EmployeeNumber1] AS [EmployeeNumber]
FROM    ( 
            SELECT      [Extent1].[EmployeeNumber] AS [EmployeeNumber1] ,
                        [Extent2].[GroupNumber] AS [GroupNumber1]
            FROM        [dbo].[kara_emp_EmployeeStateAtDate](@Date) AS [Extent1]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent2] ON ( [Extent2].[GroupNumber] IS NOT NULL )
                                                              AND ( [Extent1].[EmployeeNumber] = [Extent2].[EmployeeNumber] )
        ) AS [Filter1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Groups] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[GroupNumber1] = [Extent3].[GroupNumber]
WHERE   [Extent3].[Title] LIKE N'%XYZ%'
```

I dont know why, but EF joins function with Employee table again and take GroupNumber field from Employee table.

```
SELECT      [Extent1].[EmployeeNumber] AS [EmployeeNumber1] ,
                            [Extent2].[GroupNumber] AS [GroupNumber1]
                FROM        [dbo].[kara_emp_EmployeeStateAtDate](@Date) AS [Extent1]
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent2] ON ( [Extent2].[GroupNumber] IS NOT NULL )
                                                                  AND ( [Extent1].[EmployeeNumber] = [Extent2].[EmployeeNumber] )
```

It causes wrong vlaue, beacuse I changed GroupNumber value in the function. 
Why EF joins function with Employee table again?

**Edit:**
TSql generated with the following code:

```
IQueryable<Employee> employeeSearchResult = this.Context.EmployeeStateAtDate(persianDate.ToDateTime());
    var result = employeeSearchResult.Where(q => q.Group.Title.contains("XYZ")).ToList()
```

```
SELECT 
    [Filter1].[Emp_No1] AS [Emp_No], 
    [Filter1].[Pers_No1] AS [Pers_No], 
    [Filter1].[Name1] AS [Name], 
    [Filter1].[Family1] AS [Family], 
    [Filter1].[NationalId1] AS [NationalId], 
    [Filter1].[MobileNumber1] AS [MobileNumber], 
    [Filter1].[Email1] AS [Email], 
    [Filter1].[Address1] AS [Address], 
    [Filter1].[Tel1] AS [Tel], 
    [Filter1].[Emp_Date1] AS [Emp_Date], 
    [Filter1].[End_Date1] AS [End_Date], 
    [Filter1].[Birth_Date1] AS [Birth_Date], 
    [Filter1].[Pos_No1] AS [Pos_No], 
    [Filter1].[Sec_No1] AS [Sec_No], 
    [Filter1].[Grade_No1] AS [Grade_No], 
    [Filter1].[Emp_Type1] AS [Emp_Type], 
    [Filter1].[IsCut1] AS [IsCut], 
    [Filter1].[Cut_Reason1] AS [Cut_Reason], 
    [Filter1].[HasBreakfast1] AS [HasBreakfast], 
    [Filter1].[HasLunch1] AS [HasLunch], 
    [Filter1].[HasDinner1] AS [HasDinner], 
    [Filter1].[DelayFloatingTime1] AS [DelayFloatingTime], 
    [Filter1].[HurryFloatingTime1] AS [HurryFloatingTime], 
    [Filter1].[ExitFloatingTime1] AS [ExitFloatingTime], 
    [Filter1].[MaxFloatingTime1] AS [MaxFloatingTime], 
    [Filter1].[MaxFloatingCount1] AS [MaxFloatingCount], 
    [Filter1].[FloatingToMor1] AS [FloatingToMor], 
    [Filter1].[InformWay1] AS [InformWay], 
    [Filter1].[InformGh1] AS [InformGh], 
    [Filter1].[InformMorMam1] AS [InformMorMam], 
    [Filter1].[InformIO1] AS [InformIO], 
    [Filter1].[Is_Karmand1] AS [Is_Karmand], 
    [Filter1].[Sys_Active1] AS [Sys_Active], 
    [Filter1].[Esteh_Save_Main1] AS [Esteh_Save_Main], 
    [Filter1].[Esteh_Save1] AS [Esteh_Save], 
    [Filter1].[Min_Shab1] AS [Min_Shab], 
    [Filter1].[Is_Janbaz1] AS [Is_Janbaz], 
    [Filter1].[Janbaz_Tim1] AS [Janbaz_Tim], 
     CAST( [Filter1].[Janbaz_E_T1] AS smallint) AS [C1], 
    [Filter1].[Grp_No1] AS [Grp_No], 
    [Filter1].[Sabet_Ez1] AS [Sabet_Ez], 
    [Filter1].[Nbat_Prsnt1] AS [Nbat_Prsnt], 
    [Filter1].[Fix_Kar1] AS [Fix_Kar], 
    [Filter1].[Is_Uniq1] AS [Is_Uniq], 
    [Filter1].[Karkerd31] AS [Karkerd3], 
    [Filter1].[Grp1_No1] AS [Grp1_No], 
    [Filter1].[Grp2_No1] AS [Grp2_No], 
    [Filter1].[Grp3_No1] AS [Grp3_No], 
    [Filter1].[Grp4_No1] AS [Grp4_No], 
    [Filter1].[Grp5_No1] AS [Grp5_No], 
    [Filter1].[Ez_Type1] AS [Ez_Type], 
    [Filter1].[Mazad_Time1] AS [Mazad_Time], 
    [Filter1].[Prev_BNOver1] AS [Prev_BNOver], 
    [Filter1].[After_BNOver1] AS [After_BNOver], 
    [Filter1].[Bain_BNOver1] AS [Bain_BNOver], 
    [Filter1].[Holiday_BNOver1] AS [Holiday_BNOver], 
    [Filter1].[Almosanna1] AS [Almosanna], 
    [Filter1].[Barcode1] AS [Barcode], 
    [Filter1].[Holiday_KasrEsth1] AS [Holiday_KasrEsth], 
    [Filter1].[Kasr_EsthType1] AS [Kasr_EsthType], 
    [Filter1].[Kasr_Esth1] AS [Kasr_Esth], 
    [Filter1].[Gender1] AS [Gender], 
    [Filter1].[HurryTime1] AS [HurryTime], 
    [Filter1].[IsNaft1] AS [IsNaft], 
    [Filter1].[NaftKasrKh1] AS [NaftKasrKh], 
    [Filter1].[NaftIncKh1] AS [NaftIncKh], 
    [Filter1].[NaftKhPlace1] AS [NaftKhPlace], 
    [Filter1].[DelayTime1] AS [DelayTime], 
    [Filter1].[ServiceNumber1] AS [ServiceNumber], 
    [Filter1].[Mazad_TimeRz1] AS [Mazad_TimeRz], 
    [Filter1].[MinPrevOver1] AS [MinPrevOver], 
    [Filter1].[MinBainOver1] AS [MinBainOver], 
    [Filter1].[MinAfterOver1] AS [MinAfterOver], 
    [Filter1].[MinHolidOver1] AS [MinHolidOver], 
    [Filter1].[FloatingType1] AS [FloatingType], 
    [Filter1].[MaxDayOver1] AS [MaxDayOver], 
    [Filter1].[MaxHolidOver1] AS [MaxHolidOver], 
    [Filter1].[Mazad_TimeR1] AS [Mazad_TimeR], 
    [Filter1].[Holiday_KasrBh1] AS [Holiday_KasrBh], 
    [Filter1].[HospitalProductivityId1] AS [HospitalProductivityId], 
    [Filter1].[MJobran1] AS [MJobran], 
    [Filter1].[RJobran1] AS [RJobran], 
    [Filter1].[WF_SpecialKartabl1] AS [WF_SpecialKartabl], 
    [Filter1].[MonthOfKhedmat1] AS [MonthOfKhedmat], 
    [Filter1].[HardWorkPercent1] AS [HardWorkPercent], 
    [Filter1].[HasUnusualTurnShift1] AS [HasUnusualTurnShift], 
    [Filter1].[MaxHardWorkMors1] AS [MaxHardWorkMors], 
    [Filter1].[UserDevicePassword1] AS [UserDevicePassword], 
    [Filter1].[UserDevicePrivilage1] AS [UserDevicePrivilage], 
    [Filter1].[UserDeviceEnabled1] AS [UserDeviceEnabled], 
    [Filter1].[Ejbari_Mor1] AS [Ejbari_Mor], 
    [Filter1].[UserDeviceAuth1] AS [UserDeviceAuth], 
    [Filter1].[UserDeviceCardId1] AS [UserDeviceCardId], 
    [Filter1].[MilkFeedingTime1] AS [MilkFeedingTime], 
    [Filter1].[MilkFeedingStartDate1] AS [MilkFeedingStartDate], 
    [Filter1].[MilkFeedingEndDate1] AS [MilkFeedingEndDate]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Emp_No] AS [Emp_No1], [Extent1].[Pers_No] AS [Pers_No1], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent1].[Family] AS [Family1], [Extent1].[NationalId] AS [NationalId1], [Extent1].[MobileNumber] AS [MobileNumber1], [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email1], [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address1], [Extent1].[Tel] AS [Tel1], [Extent1].[Emp_Date] AS [Emp_Date1], [Extent1].[End_Date] AS [End_Date1], [Extent1].[Birth_Date] AS [Birth_Date1], [Extent1].[Pos_No] AS [Pos_No1], [Extent1].[Sec_No] AS [Sec_No1], [Extent1].[Grade_No] AS [Grade_No1], [Extent1].[Emp_Type] AS [Emp_Type1], [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender1], [Extent1].[IsCut] AS [IsCut1], [Extent1].[Cut_Reason] AS [Cut_Reason1], [Extent1].[HasBreakfast] AS [HasBreakfast1], [Extent1].[HasLunch] AS [HasLunch1], [Extent1].[HasDinner] AS [HasDinner1], [Extent1].[DelayTime] AS [DelayTime1], [Extent1].[HurryTime] AS [HurryTime1], [Extent1].[FloatingType] AS [FloatingType1], [Extent1].[MJobran] AS [MJobran1], [Extent1].[RJobran] AS [RJobran1], [Extent1].[DelayFloatingTime] AS [DelayFloatingTime1], [Extent1].[HurryFloatingTime] AS [HurryFloatingTime1], [Extent1].[ExitFloatingTime] AS [ExitFloatingTime1], [Extent1].[MaxFloatingTime] AS [MaxFloatingTime1], [Extent1].[MaxFloatingCount] AS [MaxFloatingCount1], [Extent1].[FloatingToMor] AS [FloatingToMor1], [Extent1].[MaxDayOver] AS [MaxDayOver1], [Extent1].[MaxHolidOver] AS [MaxHolidOver1], [Extent1].[MinPrevOver] AS [MinPrevOver1], [Extent1].[MinBainOver] AS [MinBainOver1], [Extent1].[MinAfterOver] AS [MinAfterOver1], [Extent1].[MinHolidOver] AS [MinHolidOver1], [Extent1].[Prev_BNOver] AS [Prev_BNOver1], [Extent1].[After_BNOver] AS [After_BNOver1], [Extent1].[Bain_BNOver] AS [Bain_BNOver1], [Extent1].[Holiday_BNOver] AS [Holiday_BNOver1], [Extent1].[Min_Shab] AS [Min_Shab1], [Extent1].[Ez_Type] AS [Ez_Type1], [Extent1].[Mazad_Time] AS [Mazad_Time1], [Extent1].[Mazad_TimeR] AS [Mazad_TimeR1], [Extent1].[Mazad_TimeRz] AS [Mazad_TimeRz1], [Extent1].[InformWay] AS [InformWay1], [Extent1].[InformGh] AS [InformGh1], [Extent1].[InformMorMam] AS [InformMorMam1], [Extent1].[InformIO] AS [InformIO1], [Extent1].[Is_Karmand] AS [Is_Karmand1], [Extent1].[Sys_Active] AS [Sys_Active1], [Extent1].[Esteh_Save_Main] AS [Esteh_Save_Main1], [Extent1].[Esteh_Save] AS [Esteh_Save1], [Extent1].[Is_Janbaz] AS [Is_Janbaz1], [Extent1].[Janbaz_Tim] AS [Janbaz_Tim1], [Extent1].[Janbaz_E_T] AS [Janbaz_E_T1], [Extent1].[Grp_No] AS [Grp_No1], [Extent1].[Sabet_Ez] AS [Sabet_Ez1], [Extent1].[Nbat_Prsnt] AS [Nbat_Prsnt1], [Extent1].[Fix_Kar] AS [Fix_Kar1], [Extent1].[Is_Uniq] AS [Is_Uniq1], [Extent1].[Karkerd3] AS [Karkerd31], [Extent1].[Grp1_No] AS [Grp1_No1], [Extent1].[Grp2_No] AS [Grp2_No1], [Extent1].[Grp3_No] AS [Grp3_No1], [Extent1].[Grp4_No] AS [Grp4_No1], [Extent1].[Grp5_No] AS [Grp5_No1], [Extent1].[Almosanna] AS [Almosanna1], [Extent1].[Barcode] AS [Barcode1], [Extent1].[Kasr_EsthType] AS [Kasr_EsthType1], [Extent1].[Kasr_Esth] AS [Kasr_Esth1], [Extent1].[Holiday_KasrEsth] AS [Holiday_KasrEsth1], [Extent1].[Holiday_KasrBh] AS [Holiday_KasrBh1], [Extent1].[ServiceNumber] AS [ServiceNumber1], [Extent1].[MonthOfKhedmat] AS [MonthOfKhedmat1], [Extent1].[HardWorkPercent] AS [HardWorkPercent1], [Extent1].[HasUnusualTurnShift] AS [HasUnusualTurnShift1], [Extent1].[HospitalProductivityId] AS [HospitalProductivityId1], [Extent1].[IsNaft] AS [IsNaft1], [Extent1].[NaftKasrKh] AS [NaftKasrKh1], [Extent1].[NaftIncKh] AS [NaftIncKh1], [Extent1].[NaftKhPlace] AS [NaftKhPlace1], [Extent1].[MaxHardWorkMors] AS [MaxHardWorkMors1], [Extent1].[UserDevicePassword] AS [UserDevicePassword1], [Extent1].[UserDevicePrivilage] AS [UserDevicePrivilage1], [Extent1].[UserDeviceEnabled] AS [UserDeviceEnabled1], [Extent1].[UserDeviceAuth] AS [UserDeviceAuth1], [Extent1].[UserDeviceCardId] AS [UserDeviceCardId1], [Extent1].[Ejbari_Mor] AS [Ejbari_Mor1], [Extent1].[MilkFeedingTime] AS [MilkFeedingTime1], [Extent1].[MilkFeedingStartDate] AS [MilkFeedingStartDate1], [Extent1].[MilkFeedingEndDate] AS [MilkFeedingEndDate1], [Extent1].[WF_SpecialKartabl] AS [WF_SpecialKartabl1], [Extent2].[Grp_No] AS [Grp_No2]
        FROM  [dbo].[kara_emp_EmployeeStateAtDate](@Date) AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Grp_No] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Emp_No] = [Extent2].[Emp_No])
        ) AS [Filter1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Groups] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[Grp_No2] = [Extent3].[Grp_No]
    WHERE [Extent3].[Title] LIKE N'%XYZ%'


-- Date: '2016/05/02 10:16:22 ق.ظ' (Type = DateTime2)

-- Executing at 2016/05/02 10:16:31 ق.ظ +04:30

-- Completed in 31 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

**Edit2:** 
Data model is like this:

```
   public partial class Employee : Kara.Data.EntityBaseType
{
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public int? GroupNumber { get; set; }
    public int Pers_No { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
public partial class Group : Kara.Data.EntityBaseType
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public short GroupNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And this is T-SQL of function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[kara_emp_EmployeeStateAtDate]
(   
    @Date   DATETIME 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT e.[EmployeeNumber]
      ,e.[Pers_No]
      ,e.[Name]
      ,e.[Family]
      , CASE  
            WHEN eg.GroupNumber IS NOT NULL THEN eg.GroupNumber
            ELSE e.GroupNumber
        END AS GroupNumber
      FROM [Employee] AS e 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  eg.EmployeeNumber, eg.NewGroupNumber AS GroupNumber
            FROM    EmpGrps AS eg
                    INNER JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT      eg3.EmployeeNumber, MAX(eg3.[DateStandard]) AS [DateStandard]
                        FROM        EmpGrps AS eg3
                        WHERE       eg3.[DateStandard] < ISNULL(@Date, GETDATE())
                        GROUP BY    eg3.EmployeeNumber          
                    ) AS    eg2 ON eg.EmployeeNumber = eg2.EmployeeNumber AND eg.[DateStandard] = eg2.[DateStandard] 
        ) AS eg ON eg.EmployeeNumber = e.EmployeeNumber
)
```

Comment: Could you try to see how it compares if you do not do the q.EmployeeNumber select, but just ToLists() after the Where?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: please see the `Edit` section

Comment: Would you please post your data model and data relation between your entities

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @MahdiFarhani: Please see `Edit2` section. I removed some field from both model and keep main field

Comment: @VahidJafari how about you mapping, do you have any configuration ?
group  in Employee must be required , Am I right? but yo didn't show any thing about this

Comment: @MahdiFarhani: No it is not required. it is time dependant and this caused I pass DateTime to SQl function to return corrent GroupNumber at that time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no way to change EF query generating strategy. I create a view in my model and add its relation exactly same as Employee table and use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right GroupNumber in Employee is nullable and you are trying to access GroupTitle without performing a null check. 
Modify your query to include null check on Group.

```
IQueryable<Employee> employeeSearchResult = this.Context.EmployeeStateAtDate(persianDate.ToDateTime());
 var result = employeeSearchResult.Where(q => q.Group != null && q.Group.Title.contains("XYZ")).Select(q => q.EmployeeN umber).ToList()
```

This should generate just one join with group.

Comment: I've done it, but nothing change and the problem is as before

Comment: The issue seems to be that the dataset returned from your db function is having same schema as Employee but it is not the table itself.
Therefore an extra join is required.
To solve this issue perform group title filtering logic in the function itself and return the required end result. Create a new function/ sp if you can't edit the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

I Think, it's because of the relation between group and employee.
try to remove the List from group.

I guess the EF try to access the Employee by group and you read employee data from a function, so the groupnumber will be diffrent.

BTW, if I were you I would use a notmapped field or something like DTO instead a SQL server function to chose a groupnumber between employee or employeegroup groupnumber.